# Least non-zero multiple of solution to linear equation system that is integer

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, upper-lower-bounds

Given a system of equations on the form $A\bar{x}=\bar{b}$, where $A\in\{-L,-L+1,\dots,L-1,L\}^{d\times d}$ (I don't know if this is the correct notation) has full rang and $\bar{b}\in\{-L,-L+1,\dots,L-1,L\}^d\setminus\bar{0}$, can we say anything about the non-zero multiple of $\bar{x}$ with the smallest magnitude? Can we find any upper bound on its magnitude somehow?

Comment: Cramer's Rule says the denominator is at most the determinant of a $d\times d$ matrix with entries bounded in absolute value by $L$, and then the Hadamard bound gives an upper bound for that determinant.

Comment: Was that helpful?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, yes! Following your suggestion, I can use the formula for the general case of Cramer's rule and multiply all elements with $\det(A)$ to make all of them integer, and combined with a formula on [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html), it appears that the magnitude of the elements of such a multiple could be as large as $L^d d^{d/2}$, which gives $O(L^d d^{(d+1)/2})$ as the magnitude of the vector. This is much larger than what I would have hoped for... But still, thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's possible to decrease this bound somehow. For example, I don't know whether $\det(A_1),\dots,\det(A_d)$ and $\det(A)$ can be mutually prime for large $\det(A)$; if not, I don't need to multiply with $\det(A)$ for all elements to be integer, and then I'm not sure whether all elements in the vector can have large magnitudes or just some of them.